# Interleave array elements

Tags: javascript

What is a fast and simple implementation of `interleave`:

```
console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4,5,6]      ,2) ); // [1,4,2,5,3,6]
console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  ,2) ); // [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4,5,6]      ,3) ); // [1,3,5,2,4,6]
console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3) ); // [1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]
```

This mimics taking the array and splitting it into *n* equal parts, and then shifting items off the front of each partial array in sequence. (*n*=2 simulates a perfect halving and single shuffle of a deck of cards.)

I don't much care exactly what happens when the number of items in the array is not evenly divisible by *n*. Reasonable answers might either interleave the leftovers, or even "punt" and throw them all onto the end.

Comment: @epascarello I thought I'd give others a shot at some rep (and possibly posting more elegant solutions :) before posting my own.

Comment: @Phrogz, it's just that...if I didn't see your name there with your rep, I'd have assumed this was an SO neophyte who just pasted their homework assignment verbatim without giving any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've been pushed to add my own answer early (**edited to fix bugs noted by RobG**):

```
function interleave(items,parts){
  var stride = Math.ceil( items.length / parts ) || 1;
  var result = [], len=items.length;
  for (var i=0;i<stride;++i){
    for (var j=i;j<len;j+=stride){
      result.push(items[j]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @RobG No, it won't; it uses `len` to decide when to stop. There is, however, a bug if `parts` is smaller than `length`. Thanks for the motivation to re-review and edit.

Comment: Where length is not evenly divisible by parts, this gives weird resluts, e.g. `interleave([0,1,2],2)` gives `[0,1,2]` so no interleaving and `([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],3)` => `[0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7]` which isn't interleaved either.

Comment: @RobG Good point. I think a `ceil` is preferable to the `floor` here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function interleave( deck, step ) {
    var copyDeck = deck.slice(),
        stop = Math.floor(copyDeck.length/step),
        newDeck = [];    
    for (var i=0; i<step; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<stop; j++) {
            newDeck[i + (j*step)] = copyDeck.shift();
        }        
    }
    if(copyDeck.length>0) {
        newDeck = newDeck.concat(copyDeck);
    }
    return newDeck;
}
```

It could be done with a counter instead of shift()

```
function interleave( deck, step ) {
    var len = deck.length,
        stop = Math.floor(len/step),
        newDeck = [],
        cnt=0;
    for (var i=0; i<step; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<stop; j++) {
            newDeck[i + (j*step)] = deck[cnt++];
        }        
    }
    if(cnt<len) {
        newDeck = newDeck.concat(deck.slice(cnt,len));
    }
    return newDeck;
}
```

And instead of appending the extras to the end, we can use ceil and exit when we run out

```
function interleave( deck, step ) {
    var copyDeck = deck.slice(),
        stop = Math.ceil(copyDeck.length/step),
        newDeck = [];    
    for (var i=0; i<step; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<stop && copyDeck.length>0; j++) {
            newDeck[i + (j*step)] = copyDeck.shift();
        }        
    }
    return newDeck;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

can i has prize? :-D

```
function interleave(a, n) {
  var i, d = a.length + 1, r = [];

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    r[i] = a[Math.floor(i * d / n % a.length)];
  }

  return r;
}
```

according to my tests `r.push(...` is faster than `r[i] = ...` so do with that as you like..

**note this only works consistently with sets perfectly divisible by n, here is the most optimized version i can come up with:**

```
function interleave(a, n) {
  var i, d = (a.length + 1) / n, r = [a[0]];

  for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    r.push(a[Math.floor(i * d) % a.length]);
  }

  return r;
}
```

O(n-1), can anyone come up with a log version? to the mathmobile! [spinning mathman logo]

Comment: If you have a remainder, you get some funny results. `console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4],3) );` or `console.log( interleave([1,2,3,4],10) );`

Comment: yeah, I don't think you can fix that with out adding "logic" to the loop as you would have to have memory to properly distribute the items. but it is highly optimized for *perfect* cases and in my defense he seemed like he only cared about perfect cases... while i'm at it i'll add the most optimized version and add a footnote -ck

Answer (score 1):

Without `for` loops (I've added some checkup for the equal blocks):

```
function interleave(arr, blocks)
{
    var len = arr.length / blocks, ret = [], i = 0;
    if (len % 1 != 0) return false;
    while(arr.length>0)
    {
       ret.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
       i += (len-1);
       if (i>arr.length-1) {i = 0; len--;}    
    }
    return ret;
}
alert(interleave([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2));
```

And playground :) http://jsfiddle.net/7tC9F/

Answer (score 1):

how about functional with recursion:

```
function interleave(a, n) {

  function f(a1, d) {

    var next = a1.length && f(a1.slice(d), d);
    a1.length = Math.min(a1.length, d);

    return function(a2) {
      if (!a1.length) {
        return false;
      }

      a2.push(a1.shift());
      if (next) {
        next(a2);
      }
      return true;
    };
  }

  var r = [], x = f(a, Math.ceil(a.length / n));
  while (x(r)) {}

  return r;
}
```

Comment: Give it an odd number and you freeze the browser. :)

Comment: @epascarello bad shortcut syntax, fixed now, i didn't get a browser freeze though, what set of values did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Phrogz was pretty close, but it didn't interleave properly. This is based on that effort:

```
function interleave(items, parts) {
   var len = items.length;
   var step = len/parts | 0;
   var result = [];

   for (var i=0, j; i<step; ++i) {
     j = i

     while (j < len) {
       result.push(items[j]);
       j += step;
     }
   }
   return result;
}

interleave([0,1,2,3], 2); // 0,2,1,3
interleave([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 2) // 0,6,1,7,2,8,3,9,4,10,5,11
interleave([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 3) // 0,4,8,1,5,9,2,6,10,3,7,11
interleave([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 4) // 0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11
interleave([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 5) // 0,2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9,11
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
function interleave(deck, base){
        var subdecks = [];
        for(count = 0; count < base; count++){
                subdecks[count] = [];
        }
        for(var count = 0, subdeck = 0; count < deck.length; count++){
                subdecks[subdeck].push(deck[count]);
                subdeck = subdeck == base - 1? 0 : subdeck + 1;
        }
        var newDeck = [];
        for(count = 0; count < base; count++){
                newDeck = newDeck.concat(subdecks[count]);
        }
        return newDeck;
}
```

Comment: it came from the top of my head just now, so it might not be the most elegant or performant, but was a nice challenge